# Using eval and exec, how to write an anonymous function?

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> compile("""
def some_function(x):
    return x+2
some_function""",'compiled function','single')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 4, in <module>
    some_function""",'compiled function','single')
  File "compiled function", line 4
    some_function
                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compile a multi-statement string with `compile`, `single` should be `exec`. Also, after you compile the code, you have to execute it and capture the globals in order to access the created function:

```
def anonymous(code):
    # To fix the indentation
    fixed_code = '\n'.join(line[4:] for line in code.splitlines())

    _globals = {}
    exec(compile(fixed_code, '<string>', 'exec'), _globals)

    if 'f' not in _globals:
        raise ValueError('You must name your function "f"')

    return _globals['f']

anonymous('''
    def f(x):
        return x + 2
''')(12)
```

Comment: This is not Python 3 code.

Comment: @LinuxDistance: Just turn `exec` into a function call and it'll work. Python 3 and Python 2 aren't that different.

Answer (score 1):

Question is not very clear, but is this the example you want?

```
>>> c=compile('''\
... def some_function(x):
...   return x+2
... print(some_function(5))
... ''','<string>','exec')
>>> exec(c)
7
>>> c=compile('7+2','<string>','eval')
>>> eval(c)
9
```